# Fill a cell with timestamp of another cell edit ONLY if another cell is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need fill a cell in google spreedsheet with the timestamp of the another cell's edition. But this timestamp should be show only if the another cell is edited with some content, not with erase the cell.

I have been try with this code, but the timestamp is shown also if i erase the another cell.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  if ([8].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) 
  {
    if ([8].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === '') 
    {
      e.range.offset(0, -7).setValue('0');
    }
    else
     e.range.offset(0, -7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Make sure our edit is a single cell in the H column
  // and that our edit has a value
  if(e.range.columnStart === 8 && e.value.length) {
    e.range.offset(0, -7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
  } else {
    e.range.offset(0, -7).setValue('0');
  }
}
```

The updated conditional now does 3 checks:

- `e.range.columnStart === 8` ensures we are starting in the H column
- `e.value.length` ensures that

  1. our edit is not blank
  2. the edit only affected a single cell as `e.value` is not available when multiple cells are edited (see: [Edit section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events))

`[8].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === ''` I removed this as `indexOf` cannot return an empty string. It would always evaluate to false and was the reason for all edits updating the timestamp.

EDIT: [Documentation for columnStart](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/14/benchmark-event-objects-for-google-apps-script/), still looking for an official google source. `e.range.getHeight() === 1 && e.range.getWidth() === 1 && e.range.getColumn() === 8` is a verified alternative.

Comment: Do you have a reference for columnStart?

Comment: @Cooper Added the documentation that I was using to the main answer.  I'm still looking for an official google documentation for it