# Overwriting data in a cell in column A if the cell in the same row of Column J is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script

Background: I am not a programmer.  I am a single point of failure for a rural transit agency - when it comes to operations.  We do not have an organic 'IT section', so everything we do is on a learn-it-as-you-go basis.

This should help clear up some of the ignorance that may show up in my question. :)

What I have now will find an empty cell in my range of J:J and fill it with <######>.  What I want to do is find a NON_BLANK CELL in the range of J:J and overwrite what is Column A with the contents of Column J for that row.  The spreadsheet I will be using this on has 20,000+ rows and is growing daily.

```
function fillEmptyCells() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = ss.getRange("J:J")
    .offset(0, 0, ss.getDataRange()
        .getNumRows());
range.setValues(range.getValues()
    .map(function (row) {
        return row.map(function (cell) {
            return cell === '' ? '<######>' : cell;
        });
    }));
```

}`

An explanation of the data:

Column A: Date/time group created by google when information was submitted from a form

Column B - I: Data about an instance - vehicle name, route, location, and numbers of pick-up based on type

Column J: Automatically created when data was not correctly inserted by user (from a tablet in vehicles) and was entered in the office at a later date.

A snippet of my data is:

6/24/2020 0:00:00   ERROR CORR  West    38.2127700  -84.8901400 42  0   3   0
6/11/2020 0:00:00   ERROR CORR  West    38.2127700  -84.8901400 39  0   0   0   2/5/2020 0:00:00

This link takes you to a test section of data:
[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_7_p5P7Og9tqhhkQq6M2ZOVFeSI9P4ScXAFAhji0OM0/edit?usp=sharing)

I found this in my searches - but it did not seem to be going in the same direction I was.
[Question already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825225/fill-a-cell-with-timestamp-of-another-cell-edit-only-if-another-cell-is-not-blan)

If I am going in the right direction - please help steer me to what I need to change in the script (and why if you are feeling froggy).  If I am totally off - point me in the direction I need to be going.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a new solution for you:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spsh.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheetSize=sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String).length; //calculate the size of column A
  
  for (i = 1; i <=sheetSize ; i++) { 
    
    var J_value = sheet.getRange(i,10).getValue()
    if(J_value!=''){sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(J_value)}
    
  }//end for
  
}//end function
```

I actually check every cell of column J. If a J cell is not empty, then I copy the value to column A in the same row.

The script that I just shared with you is very quick.
However, if the spreadsheet file has too many rows, then you can run this script multiple times for different range of rows. For example:

1st run:  `for (i = 1; i <=5000; i++)`
2nd run:  `for (i = 5001; i <=10000; i++)`
..
..
or even create multiple scripts that take care of different ranges.

Comment: Thank you! I was not quite in the right direction.  

The range - initially will have to run the gamut of the spreadsheet.  I intend on making this a script that runs automatically, either at midnight or if I can figure the coding out as part of the update sent from our tablets in the office - so it would only have to apply to the single row at the time of input.